# tableView in xib not picking up datasource delegate methods in associated view controller

Tags: iphone, uikit

My main xib file has a tab bar controller and each tab is linked to a different xib.

One of the tabs is a nav controller and its view controller is linked to a xib as per this [answer](http://tinyurl.com/3lh3df5).

When I run the app I get the below error. its as if its not even looking in the view controller for these methods.

i have tried everything including using a different xib, checking the links in interface builder i.e. the tableview's delegate and datasource.  i have implemented the required protocol methods in the vc e.g. numberofrowsinsection.

as soon as i remove the datasource link in the xib the error goes away.

EDIT:  When I add this view controller's view to the main window (just to test) the tableview loads without issues.  So it seems it only happens when I use it as part of the nav controller and tab controller.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6120ae0'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00dc45a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00f18313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00dc60bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00d35966 __*forwarding*** + 966
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d35522
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50    5   UIKit
>   0x001d32b7 -[UISectionRowData
>   refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1834    6   UIKit
>   0x001d0d88 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 108   7   UIKit
>   0x00084677 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 132   8   UIKit
>   0x00091708 -[UITableView reloadData] + 773    9   UIKit
>   0x0008e844 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 42     10  QuartzCore
>   0x016aea5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181   11  QuartzCore
>   0x016b0ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220    12  QuartzCore
>   0x016560b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
>     13  QuartzCore                          0x01657294
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292    14  QuartzCore
>   0x0165746d
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
>     15  CoreFoundation                      0x00da589b
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 27    16
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00d3a6e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 295     17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d031d7
>   __CFRunLoopRun + 1575     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d02840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d02761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    20  GraphicsServices
>   0x00ffc1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  21  GraphicsServices
>   0x00ffc289 GSEventRun + 115   22  UIKit
>   0x00024c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160   23  MyPractice
>   0x00002339 main + 121     24  MyPractice
>   0x000022b5 start + 53 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This log message:

```
[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Implies that the `UITableView dataSource` method is being sent to an instance of `UIViewController`, not an instance of your subclass. How are you initialising your VC? If you're initialising it from within a XIB, have you correctly set the VC's class to your subclass?

Comment: I don't have a subclass.  I just created a viewcontroller with xib placed a tableview in the xib and linked the datasource to the file owner.  Then I used this view controller as above

Comment: When you say you've 'implemented the required protocol methods in the vc', those methods are implemented by creating a subclass. There's no alternative way of implementing those methods. Where have you put them?

Comment: sorry yes you are right.  I have a subclass which have these methods implemented.  the xib has a tableview and its linked to this subclass

Comment: I was setting the XIB but not the class.  I didnt realise you had to do both!  Stupid!  You rock mate!